# Merkle tree H(RBIT(X) ⊕ Y) instead of H(X || Y)

Tags: encryption, hash

I was reading [Can XOR be used in a Merkle Tree instead of concatenation?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/89847/can-xor-be-used-in-a-merkle-tree-instead-of-concatenation?rq=1) and had the idea of reversing bits for either X or Y before the XOR combiner, to indicate the order. So instead of H(X ⊕ Y) we could use H(RBIT(X) ⊕ Y) (or H(X ⊕ RBIT(Y))).

The cost of both RBIT and XOR instructions are negligible on most modern CPUs compared to an additional hashing round, performance would (almost) double...

Assuming also that X and Y are mutually independent (which is the case in many constructions where the leafs of the merkle tree are pseudo-randomly generated, or randomized), would this make a secure combiner? Why (not)?

Answer (score 1):

The problems mentioned in [Can XOR be used in a Merkle Tree instead of concatenation?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/89847/can-xor-be-used-in-a-merkle-tree-instead-of-concatenation?rq=1) are just special cases of a fundamental problem: the construction is not second-preimage resistant. In fact, it is even worse in the sense that you can find a preimage with *any* $X$ value you like (similarly any $Y$ value you like).

You can open a Merkle-tree node $H( X \oplus Y)$ to any other values $X'$ and $Y'$ as long as $X \oplus Y = X' \oplus Y'$. If you can do this, then you can open a Merkle-tree leaf to literally *any* value. Flipping/inverting some bits (and indeed, any linear operation) won't make this attack any harder.

Answer (score 0):

Your design has a formatting flaw: A non-leaf node can have the same hash as some leaf node with corresponding data. Having all the data generated randomly does not mitigate it, because you can't force the attacker to follow this rule. (If you assume there is no such attacker, maybe you don't need HMAC at all.) The impact depends on the application, maybe attacker can just crash your app, but it is generally tricky to say “this cannot be abused in a meaningful way.”. Once your protocol is full of similar items, attacker is likely to find a meaningful way.

Assuming that:

- RBIT is a bit negation and
- you are talking just about **binary** trees and
- you fix the flaw above, e.g., by adding a different prefix to leaves and non-leaves

it looks like it **might** be secure at first sight. However, such statements are **tricky**. There are various other designs that might look secure, but they aren't (e.g. [various wannabe-hmac functions](https://blog.skullsecurity.org/2012/everything-you-need-to-know-about-hash-length-extension-attacks). Proving the security of your scheme might require some additional assumptions about the hash function, which is another tricky part.

Another reason for not using it is that you might achieve a similar performance gain in a more standard way. If you are using SHA256, just switch to SHA224. (If you are using SHA-512, just switch to SHA-384.) Since SHA-224 uses a 512-bit block, two hashes plus a 8-bit prefix is just 2*224+8=456b, which is still a single block, so the hash computation time should remain ± the same. (It might still a bit vary due to padding, but this is implementation-specific and probably just a minor thing.) For a 512-bit block, anything strictly smaller (504 bits and less) is just one block. (Once you utilize the whole block, you need another one for padding.) The same argument is there for SHA-384 and its 1024-bit blocks. And it might also work the same way for SHA3 or other functions, but it needs checking its parameters (block size and output size).